# What type of chilli plant is this?

Tags: identification, chili

A friend gave me some seeds from a chilli which have now produced some fruit.
I would like to know what type it is. He thinks it might be "bhut jolokia" or "carolina reaper" but is not sure. After seeing photos on line for those two it seems closer to the "bhut jolokia" but still enough differences in the leaves (tear drop shape instead of heart shape) and fruit (short almost round instead of long) to not be sure.

[image: Red Chilli]

[image: Yellow Chilli]

Comment: Could it be a rocoto chill ? Does it have black seeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am fairly sure it is Habanero chili.  I grew some this last season...check out the pics here: [habanero chilis](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=habanero)

Comment: The leaves definitely look habanero-like rather than Bhut-like. And the red one doesn't have a tail so it's not a Reaper. So I'd say Red and Orange(?) Habaneros.

Comment: @stormy I concur about it looking like a habanero. It could also be a Scotch Bonnet (they look a lot the same). Habaneros have delayed heat while Scotch Bonnets don't, in my experience tasting them (which isn't considerable, yet). There are a lot of peppers that look like habaneros (such as the varied seasoning peppers, which lack strong heat), but habaneros are probably more common. It could be a Red Savina Habanero, or a regular red one, or a Caribbean Red Habanero—or others, maybe.

Comment: The vegetative part looks anemic.  I grew 5 different of each type.  I dried them slowly and the larger pods such as Habaneros I slightly cooked/roasted.  Strung them all up on a few strings and have a 3' long triple deep bunch of yummy peppers.  I am going to learn to roast them properly.  Mine are a surprise heat...takes a bit but then hold on to your seat!  Peppers are one of the best crops of all.  The leaves of mine were smaller and dark green.  (full of white fly too, but did not deter my peppers).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a red habanero chilli.

Answer (score 0):

OK 2 be exactly true that's a scotch bonnet. One of the hottest chilies that are available for people to buy. 14 times hotter than jalapenos. Me and my dad have a huge garden filled with plants and chilies. I have grown bonnets and these in the pictures are the same chili. Don't try eating it straight as it may be too hot to handle and can cause gastritis. Mix with food to get balance.